# Golang Oauth2 Service account returns empty refresh token string

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, service-accounts

I'm having a problem with the google/Oauth2 package when attempting to authenticate through the service account using a server to server authentication. Google responds with a token struct with an empty refresh token string, and the token expires in 1h, which I can't refresh as I don't have a refresh token.
Here is the code snippet I'm using:

```
/*
import(
    "github.com/google/go-containerregistry/pkg/authn"
    gcr "github.com/google/go-containerregistry/pkg/name"
    "github.com/google/go-containerregistry/pkg/v1/remote"
)

*/
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", path, serviceAccountFilePath))
if err != nil {
   log.Fatalf("Failed to read GCP service account key file: %s", err)
}
ctx := context.Background()
fmt.Println(scopes)
creds, err := google.CredentialsFromJSON(ctx, data, scopes...)

if err != nil {
   log.Fatalf("Failed to load GCP service account credentials: %s", err)

}
t, _ := creds.TokenSource.Token()
fmt.Println(t.Expiry.Sub(time.Now()).String(), t.RefreshToken, ">>>")

r, err := gcr.NewRegistry("https://gcr.io")
if err != nil {
 log.Fatalf("failed to ping registry: %s", err)
}
authToken := authn.FromConfig(authn.AuthConfig{
    RegistryToken: t.AccessToken,
})

repo, err := gcr.NewRepository(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", urlPrefix, imageName))
repo.Registry = r
list, err := remote.List(repo, remote.WithAuth(authToken))
```

[image: output]

I tried different ways while using the service account for authentication, such as the config and JWT but I still got the same result.

Comment: Wrap your token source in [ReuseTokenSource](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2#ReuseTokenSource) and a new token is requested only when necessary.

Comment: that way creds.TokenSource = oauth2.ReuseTokenSource(t, creds.TokenSource)?

Comment: I think this is quite redundant as if you take a look at the func CredentialsFromJSON, it uses this func [tokenSource](https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/b177c21ac9b48a8e3b2a6824b49de2397bd9e721/google/google.go#L155) which is going to call reusable token source under the hood

Comment: In terms of oauth2, in order to get a refresh token, you need to add  `offline_access` to the requested scopes and also use `response_type=code` for the auth query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto)'s hints, I solved the problem.

So the fix for the such problem was by not using the credentials out of google.CredentialsFromJSON() func will return the token source without refreshing the token in case of passing the service account to that function, which means that you can't refresh your token when it expires again later. Also, anticipating and re-authenticating to generate a new token didn't work for me (no clue why).

So I had to convert the JSON of the service account into JWT through this func instead

```
scopes := []string{"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"}
tokenSource, err := google.JWTAccessTokenSourceWithScope(serviceAccountFileBytes, scopes...)
```

The reason that this one works, is because it creates the JWT token internally through the service_account's properties such as  client email and client_id and private_key as GCP allows us to create our local JWT tokens and encode them.

Answer (score 1):

Service accounts don't need / use refresh tokens.

Refresh tokens are used for offline access by standard Oauth2 authorization.  If the user is offline then the application can use the refresh tokens to get an new access token and make requests on behalf of the user.

With service accounts they are already preauthorized and have access to the data they have.  A request should return an access token once that access token expires after an hour you just make a new authorization request to get a new access token.

Refresh tokens are unnecessary in the case of service accounts.  When the access token expires just run your auth code again to get a new one.   Its saving you a step.

Comment: so you mean, if the token is invalid, I should create a new token through re-authenticating?, do you have an example of that?, I thought that when using .Token() function it's going to handle the expired tokens and return me back the active one

Comment: What api are you trying to connect to, I will try to find you an example.  In the mean time here is one for Google drive api.   It should be close for each of the apis you just need to change the service object.

Comment: I've a problem for some reason if not using credentials file, I've been using TokenSource and generating tokens through credentials that I could get from the func CredentialsFromJSON while passing serviceAccount to it, it never refreshes the tokens, I even checked manually on token expiration to avoid making the oauth2 package to send the request to get me a new token when the token is expired cuz when coming through Service Accounts I don't have a refresh token. I made my own logic to re-authenticate and use the new token, however that didn't work as well.

Comment: I'm trying to access docker API which requires access token that will eventually expire as I mentioned in the above comment

Comment: Nothing in your question mentions docker API mind adding a link to the api in  your question.